# How can I separate two numbers into integers when they have been entered in with a space inbetween?

Tags: c#, integer, readline

In my task I would normally use something like this

```
letters = Console.ReadLine();
c1 = letters[0];
c2 = letters[1];
```

and it would separate the 2 letters entered into c1 and c2, but since I'm now working with integers that may or may not be only one digit, I need a way to separate them into a1 and a2. If the entered numbers are 9 and 10, "9 10", it would give a1 the value of 9 and a2 the value of 10. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

```
string[] parsed = letters.Split(' ');
string c1 = parsed[0];
string c2 = parsed[1];
```